# How can I get primary device email address using Android Studio and React native?

Tags: react-native

```
 public static String getAccountManagerEmails(Context context) {
 Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();}

 @Override
 protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
 return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getAccountManagerEmails(this),
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());}
```

By doing this my app is crashing so How to pass context from getAccountManagerEmail() to public method ?